# Make message disappear after several seconds

Tags: javascript, html, django

I'm displaying error messages on the screen and i want these messages to disappear after X seconds. I'm using a simple script that works if one message is displayed on the screen.
If two messages are displayed, see example below, only the first message is disappeared, the second one remains on the screen.
How can i remove both messages?

[image: Messages]

I'm using this script:

```
setTimeout(function() {
  $('#message').fadeOut('slow');
}, 15000);
```

Script that produces the messages.

```
{% if form.errors %}
  {% for field in form %}
    {% for error in field.errors %}
      <div id="message">
        <div class="alert alert-warning alert-dismissible" role="alert">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
            {{ error|escape }}
        </div>
      </div>
    {% endfor %}
  {% endfor %}
  {% for error in form.non_field_errors %}
    <div class="alert alert-warning alert-dismissible" role="alert">
      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        {{ error|escape }}
    </div>
  {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

Thank you for help.

Comment: use a class (`.message`)instead of an id. Then `$('.message')` should return an array, so call fadeOut on each element of the array.

Comment: can we see the script that displays the messages?

Comment: @MrPizzaGuy i've included the script that displays the messages.

Comment: @Pac0 could you please show me an example?

Comment: @paniklas KevinJohnson's did pull the trigger first, see their answer

Comment: @MrPizzaGuy. Any suggestions worth trying?

Comment: @Pac0 please send me if you have any suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

if it doesn't work just try:

```js
setTimeout(function(){
  $('.message').hide();
},1000);
```

Comment: wait, what did u change, the javascript or the  HTML? try both, make them class selector, and retry, there was only 1 error and i selved it, if there is more tell me the error line and i'l fix it, Thanks for trying my code

Comment: I changed both to class and it doesn't work. I just tried again.

Comment: I used id instead of class with hide and the first message disappears however the second remains. Thank you for help.

Comment: then try preventing the second one from appearing or use notply plugin, http://github.com/kevinj045/notply

Comment: did u use notply?

Answer (score 0):

After trying the following code all messages disappeared from the screen.

```
$(".alert").show(() => {
    setTimeout(() => {
        $(".alert").fadeTo(500, 1).slideUp(500, () => {

            $(message).hide();
        })
    }, 5000)
});
```

Thank you all for your time!